# Read grades from file, incorrect format for converting string to double error

Tags: c#, file-io, console-application

I am reading a string from file and I try to convert it to double, but it says:

> 1.55
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.    at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value,
>   NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)    at
>   System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)    at ConsoleApp6.Logic.read()
>   in C:\Users\sashk\Source\Repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\Class2.cs:line
>   123    at ConsoleApp6.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\sashk\Source\Repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\Program.cs:line 19

It prints the first grade but it blocks on the second double, I don't know the reason why. Here is the code:

```
public void read(){
   string[] textes = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\sashk\Source\Repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\save.txt", Encoding.Default);
   double[] gread = new double[40];
   var excluded = new[] { "Name:", "FacultyNumber:", "Grades:", "AverageGrade:" };
   var dot =  "," ;
   List<string> texts = new List<string>();
   int i = 0;
   int z = 0;
   foreach (string text in textes){
      string[] words = textes[i].Split(' ');
      for (int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++){
         if (!excluded.Contains(words[j])){
            texts.Add(words[j]);
            //  Console.WriteLine(words[j]); 
         }
      }
      for (int j = 3; j < texts.Count; j++){
         if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(texts[j], @"^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я ]+$")){
            var newValue = texts[j].Replace(',', '.');
            Console.WriteLine(newValue);
            gread[z] = Convert.ToDouble(newValue);
            z++;
         }
      }
      addStudent(texts[1], Convert.ToInt32(texts[2]), gread);
      i++;
   }
   //for (int j = 0; j < texts.Count; j++)
   // {
   //     Console.WriteLine(texts[j]);
   // }
}
```

The content of the file is this :

```
Name: as FacultyNumber: 4 Grades: 1,55 5,55 9,55 AverageGrade: 5
Name: asd FacultyNumber: 2 Grades: 1,23 4,56 7,89 AverageGrade: 4,56
Name: ad FacultyNumber: 3 Grades: 2,55 4,55 7,55 AverageGrade: 4,33
Name: ddd FacultyNumber: 1 Grades: 2,55 5,55 9,55 AverageGrade: 4
```

It's seemingly formatted correctly but I don't know why it crashes? I checked for extra spaces but there aren't.

Comment: You should debug your app. In debug mode, it will stop when the exception is thrown. Then it's easy to see where and with which input data it fails.

Comment: your question is different from your code

Comment: no it doesn't       for (int j = 3; j < texts.Count; j++){
         if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(texts[j], @"^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я ]+$")){
            var newValue = texts[j].Replace(',', '.');
            Console.WriteLine(newValue);
            gread[z] = Convert.ToDouble(newValue);
            z++;
         }
      }
  converts to the string to double and puts it in array called grades which is later assigned to the student?

Comment: Change `Console.WriteLine(newValue);` to `Console.WriteLine($"'{newValue}'");` and your issue will be more obvious...   Also, without wanting to give the game away, try `Console.WriteLine(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("", @"^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я ]+$"));`

Comment: … and you may want to check if your test "if string contains other characters than a-z it must be a double" is ideal. After this you could use double.TryParse that allows you to easily log errors.